# Why not modify a Set within a parallelStream?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I read that it was a bad idea to modify a set within a parallelStream.

I can understand that there are concurrency issues, but is there any workaround?

Can we synchronize or would it lose the interest of the parallelStream?

Comment: Synchronizing the `Set` access would ensure a consistent `Set` state but possibly degrade the performance and doesn’t solve ordering issues. If the particular operation is unordered anyway, you may live with it, but there is no general answer, i.e. without a specific use case, to the question.

Comment: Moreover, it should modify nothing outside of stream. This gives you required possibility to parallelize a stream.

Comment: Well that's why I would like to do. I have a class that has two HashSets fields, and I want to populate them based on the parallelStream's data. Is that possible? Am I thinking this wrong?

Comment: So, the primary goal is to populate the sets (say, using `forEach`) and the order is irrelevant (i.e. we’re not talking about `LinkedHashSet`)? Then, it might work (assuming you’re doing measures for thread safe access), though it still depends on the circumstances, whether there is a benefit from parallel processing. Sometimes, collecting into local sets first and doing an `addAll` on the target afterwards, might be more efficient. But populating two sets in one operation will require a custom collector.

Comment: Parallel streams are supposed not to mutate variables state. Doing that may result in [ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html). Check the link to understand why. If you really need to do that, your design is probably wrong. If you need to synchronize, you are increasing additional wait time since your threads will not run independently, reducing eventual performance gains that the parallelization might provide for your problem. Check this [explanatory video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2nup6Oizpcw).